# A Right Mess Made

Tags: riddle, rhyme, wordplay

*To me, you are but a cafe

Buffet; souffle; filet; parfait

I'll be the hunter, you be the prey

Slice me in twain, and leave my tail.*

*Lower, lower, lower yet

submerged in water, never wet

Pick me and you will not regret

The leaders stay, the rest all bail.*

*Treat me as you have my kin

Pin me down, and see my sins

All spill asunder from within

My heart bleeds, though my shell prevails.*

*Rooted deep within the ground

A being of myth and tales unbound

The net's been cast, and I've been found

In full I stand, behind no veil.*

*Take them all to find my name

A right mess made, and you're to blame

Then take the rejects, cast in shame

Spin them around and they'll do the same.*

---

The first four stanzas describe my pieces, and the fifth describes my companion and I in whole. The question is, **who are we?**

<sup>Bonus points to whomever is able to point out the *cheeky* hints I've left in each of the first four stanzas.</sup>

Comment: For some reason, I'm thinking of fruit. Maybe because of all the talk of hearts bleeding but shells prevail.

Comment: Is "net" the cheeky hint in the fourth stanza?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the solution is:

> The two words **predicament** and **rotate**

Taking each stanza, one at a time:

*To me, you are but a cafe / Buffet; souffle; filet; parfait / I'll be the hunter, you be the prey / Slice me in twain, and leave my tail.*

> Gives us **predator** (since it hunts and eats its prey), which we slice in half, keeping *pred* and discarding *ator*.

*Lower, lower, lower yet / submerged in water, never wet / Pick me and you will not regret / The leaders stay, the rest all bail.*

> Gives **ice** (since we "lower" the temperature to make icecubes/bergs which sit in water but are solid not liquid, and you can use "pick" on ice), of which we keep the leaders, *ic*, and discard *e*.

*Treat me as you have my kin / Pin me down, and see my sins / All spill asunder from within / My heart bleeds, though my shell prevails.*

> Gives us **ATM** (not sure about the first line, but you use a PIN to withdraw money, which is the root of all evil), of which we keep the outer "shell" of letters, *am*, and leave behind the "heart", *t*.

*Rooted deep within the ground / A being of myth and tales unbound / The net's been cast, and I've been found / In full I stand, behind no veil.*

> Gives **[Ent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ent)** (mythical tree creatures), which we keep the entirety of.

*Take them all to find my name / A right mess made, and you're to blame*

> Putting together all the parts we kept, gives us **predicament** (which is a "right mess made").

*Then take the rejects, cast in shame / Spin them around and they'll do the same.*

> Taking all the bits we discarded, "ator", "e" & "t", we "spin them around", to get **rotate** (which also means spin around).

Comment: This answer is on point. :) Do you have the *cheeky* hint in the fourth stanza? (Hint: you do.)

Comment: "Pin me down" probably also refers to entering a PIN on an ATM.

Comment: Oof, the kerning on ATM is painful. :(

Comment: @BaileyM - So if "net" => "ent" is the cheeky hint in stanza four, what are the other ones? I guess "Treat Me As" => "TMA" => "ATM" could be three... (and yes, that kerning is horrific)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - that was my intention when I capitalised PIN, perhaps wasn't clear (was typing on mobile at the time).

Comment: You got the other cheeky hints, in 'prey', 'pick', and 'pin'. Just silly clues. :)